# Symbolic Tensor Assignment of Floats from Tensor Path

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I am attempting to implement a neural network in tensorflow 2.14 which uses the name of the image to collect 5 float32 label values. I am using the dataset.map function similar to tf.data flowers example. Whenever I attempt to create a tensor containing the 5 float values I often only get the initialization data of the tensor, 0 or 1. From my understanding doing this within a function effects the gready execution and results in usage of Symbolic Tensors. I would love to use a numpy() call to simplify the sintax of my solution but I could not overcome the issues with the gready execution not functioning.

Below is the current iteration of the function I have tried which results in only initialization values. I have initialized all of the variable tensors being stacked with (0.) float32.

```
def get_label(file_path):
  
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
  x = parts[-1]
  x = tf.strings.split(x, " ")
  for y in x:
    if tf.strings.regex_full_match(y, "K"):
      tf.add(stroke, tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.strip(y,"K"), tf.float32))
    elif tf.strings.regex_full_match(y, "O"):
      tf.add(ontime, tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.strip(y,"O"), tf.float32))
    elif tf.strings.regex_full_match(y, "I"):
      tf.add(offtime, tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.strip(y,"I"), tf.float32))
    elif tf.strings.regex_full_match(y, "F"):
      tf.add(opentime, tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.strip(y,"F"), tf.float32))
    elif tf.strings.regex_full_match(y, "R"):
      tf.add(closetime, tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.strip(y,"R"), tf.float32))
    else:
      continue
  stack_holder = tf.stack([stroke, ontime, offtime, opentime, closetime])
  return stack_holder
```

I have tried numpy() which resulted in the gready execution issues and I have tried pulling in the filepath externally and simply searching a list but assigning the variable through an alternative method but this did not help either.